# mongoose isn't finding the value

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

why does this always return invalid creds when the password is correct?
‎‎‎Thank you!‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎

```js
const schema = mongoose.Schema({
    pass: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    }
  })
const password = mongoose.model('pass', schema)

mongo().then(async (mongoose) => {
  const test = new password({
    password: 'pass'
  })
  password.findOne({ password: passwordInput }, function (err, user) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    else if (user) {
      log('LOGGED IN!')
    }
    else {
      log('Invalid creds');
    }
  });
})
```

Comment: Is the data properly persisted?

Comment: @FirminoChangani not sure what you mean by that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few issues with your code

```
const schema = mongoose.Schema({
    pass: { // <---- property name is pass not password
      type: String,
      required: true,
    }
})
```

then here

```
const test = new password({
    password: 'pass' // property name password not pass
})
```

also the above code does not save the password to db. You need to call `save()`

```
const test = new password({
    password: 'pass' // property name password not pass
})
test.save();
```

even like this it won't work because the save method is assynchronous which means it takes some time for it to get to db. So you would need to do something like this

```
const test = new password({
    password: 'pass'
})
test.save(function(){
    // this function is called after the password was saved to db
    // now you can query db
    password.findOne({ pass.....
});
```

Complete code

```
const schema = mongoose.Schema({
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    }
})
const password = mongoose.model('password', schema)

mongo().then(async (mongoose) => {
    const test = new password({
        password: 'pass'
    })
    test.save(function(){
        password.findOne({ password: passwordInput }, function (err, user) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else if (user) {
                log('LOGGED IN!')
            }  else {
                log('Invalid creds');
            }
        });
    });
})
```

Comment: thanks a lot! Sort of rushed the code which lead to so many mistakes lol.